# How to add new column to MySQL table without listing other existing columns

Tags: mysql

Say that we have a mysql table that has 100 columns. Now, I know that if we wanted to have a new column that has the sum of the values of two columns we could use the `SUM` function on the two columns after `SELECT`, but then I also have to list the names of the other 100 columns. Is there a way to have a table that has the 100 columns plus the `SUM` function without listing those columns after `SELECT`.

`SELECT c1+c2, c1, c2, c3, c4,...,c100 FROM columns`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you show sample data end expected result?

Comment: I think the horizontal scroll bar would be too taxed, @Jens

Comment: @Drew Horrible question, hilarious comments ^ ^

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design. See normalisation.

Comment: I second what Strawberry wrote. And you should only select the columns you really need, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT c1+c2, t.* FROM columns t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the wildcard (`*`):

```
SELECT *, c1 + c2 AS sum FROM columns
```